# Сравнение строк

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так в сравнении строк у меня

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'auto.php',
        type: 'post',
        scriptCharset: "windows-1251",
        data: $('form').serialize()
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data === 'Неверный пароль') {
            $('h2').text(data);
        }
        if (data === 'Пользователя с таким логином не существует') {
            $('h2').text(data);
        } else {
            window.location.href = 'report.php';
        }

    });
});
```

Почему-то всегда выполняется ветка else...

Comment: Пользуйтесь [отладкой](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/foundation/errors).  Или, на худой конец, вставьте вызов `alert(data)`.

Comment: неправильно выполняется только сравнение..
сервер возвращает то, с чем сравнивается  if-ах, в зависимости от данных..

Comment: проверила, в data все правильно.

Comment: у вас ошибка не в проверке, а в логике работы, добавьте ещё один `else` после первого `if`

Comment: if ( data === 'Неверный пароль')
    {
     alert( 'Сравнение выполнено!!! Пароль неверный!')
     $('h2').text( data );
             }
   else {
    alert( 'Строки не совпадают!');
   }
все равно на else переходит..оставила только эту часть..

Comment: Не советую делать проверку таким образом. Если даже кодировка у вас совпадает, то случайно затесавшийся даже пробельный символ, спутает вам все карты. При формировании ответа, отправляйте дополнительно какую-то переменную, которую и будете сравнивать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рискну посоветовать вам не проверять ответы с сервера таким образом. А что если вы захотите изменить сообщение? Вам придется изменять его в двух местах - клиентском и серверном коде.

Отправляйте с сервера json, например.

Самый простой пример.

Ответ сервера отправляйте в виде:

```
{success:true|false, message:"Сообщение"}
```

В частности ваши ответы будут выглядеть так:

```
{success:false, message:"Неверный пароль"}
{success:false, message:"Пользователь не существует"}
{success:true, message:"Все хорошо"}
```

В функции done, все будет легко проверяться:

```
// преобразуем ответ в объект
json = $.parseJSON(data);
// логика при удаче\неудаче
if (json.success) {
    $('h2').text(json.message);
} else {
    window.location.href = 'report.php';
}
```

В итоге получили, что логика никак не зависит от сообщений.

Comment: а на сервере ответ формировать примерно так?
если неверный пароль например..
$ask = array{success:false, message:"Неверный пароль"} 
 print json_encode ($ask);

Comment: Да, только массив в php выглядит не так.

    $response = array(
        "success" => false,
        "message" => "Неверный пароль"
    );

Comment: print json_encode(array("success"=>false,"message"=>"Неверный пароль"));

в message  получился  null..

Comment: Проверьте кодировку.

Comment: Придется вам либо использовать везде utf-8, либо писать костыли по ковертации из win1251 в utf-8 для json_encode.

Используйте utf8 =)

Comment: у меня скрипт в win-1251 написан..и браузер Chrome c кириллицей win-1251..

  $mes = mb_convert_encoding('Неверный пароль', "CP1251", "UTF-8");
  print json_encode(array("success"=>false,"message"=>$mes));

тут в $mes  пустая строка получилась..
осталось с кодировкой разобраться..

Comment: быть может

    $mes = iconv("cp1251", "UTF-8", $mes)

Comment: вопрос медленно переходит в метку php

Answer (score 2):

Я не особо понял, что вы сделали, но имел ввиду я следующее:

```
if (data == 'Неверный пароль') {
    $('h2').text(data);
} else {
    if (data == 'Пользователя с таким логином не существует') {
        $('h2').text(data);
    } else {
        window.location.href = 'report.php';
    }
}
```

Или так:

```
if (data == 'Неверный пароль' || data == 'Пользователя с таким логином не существует') {
    $('h2').text(data);
} else {
    window.location.href = 'report.php';
}
```

Comment: все равно переходит на самую последнюю ветку  else..

Comment: >все равно переходит на самую последнюю ветку else..

вывод: в `data` НЕ `'Неверный пароль'` и НЕ `'Пользователя с таким логином не существует'`